# Alexa Skill error

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to call a 3rd party API in my Alexa Skill, and I'm getting a "Session ended with reason: ERROR" in CloudWatch log. The issue appears to be in my NumberIntentHandler or my httpGet function, but I'm not sure where.

**UPDATED CODE**

**-- Handler that's getting fired --**

```
  const NumberIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'NumberIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
      let slotNum = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.number.value;
      //var myRequest = parseInt(slotNum);   
      const myRequest = parseInt(slotNum);
      console.log('NumberIntentHandler myRequest: ', myRequest);
      var options = `http://numbersapi.com/${myRequest}`;
      console.log('NumberIntentHandler options: ', options);

      // Use the async function
  const myResult = httpGet(options);
         console.log("sent     : " + options);
         console.log("received : " + myResult);
         const speechText = myResult;
         console.log('speechText: ', speechText); // Print the speechText   */ 

      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
           .speak(speechText)
           .withSimpleCard('Here is your fact: ', speechText)
           .getResponse(); 
  },
};
```

**-- Function that's getting called from the Handler --**

```
  async function httpGet(options) {
  // return new pending promise
  console.log(`~~~~~~~~~ httpGet ~~~~~~~~~`);
  console.log(`~~~~~${JSON.stringify(options)}~~~~~`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    

  const request = http.get(options, (response) => {
      // handle http errors
      if (response < 200 || response > 299) {
        reject(new Error('Failed to load page, status code: ' + response));
      }// temporary data holder
      const body = [];
      // on every content chunk, push it to the data array
      response.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk));
      // we are done, resolve promise with those joined chunks
      response.on('end', () => resolve(body.join('')));
      console.log('body: ', body[0]);
    });
    // handle connection errors of the request
    request.on('error', (err) => reject(err));    
    request.end(); 
  });
}
```

**Updated Code - Eliminated async/await/promise**

**-- Handler --**

```
const NumberIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'NumberIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
      let slotNum = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.number.value;
      //var myRequest = parseInt(slotNum);   
      const myRequest = parseInt(slotNum);
      console.log('NumberIntentHandler myRequest: ', myRequest);
      var options = `http://numbersapi.com/${myRequest}`;
      console.log('NumberIntentHandler options: ', options);

      // Use the async function
  //const myResult = httpGet(options);
    const myResult = httpGet(options, res => {

         console.log("sent     : " + options);
         console.log("received : " + myResult);
         const speechText = myResult;
         console.log('speechText: ', speechText); // Print the speechText   */ 

      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
           .speak(speechText)
           .withSimpleCard('Here is your fact: ', speechText)
           .getResponse(); 
    });         
  },
};
```

**-- Function --**

```
function httpGet(options, cb) {
  http.get(options, res => {
    console.log(`~~~~~${JSON.stringify(options)}~~~~~`);
    // simplified version without error handling
    let output = []; 
    res.on('data', d => output.push(d)); // or concat to a string instead?
    res.on('end', () => cb(output));
    console.log('output: ', output[0]);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need to call resolve with your response in httpGet.

As a side note (unrelated to your problem) - I can recommend using request-promise, it implements a very nice promise api around http and would simplify your code in this case. (I know I know, async/await are new and fun tools but in this case I would go with "simpler" :) ).

Also, if I remember correctly, the callback for http.get is being invoked with only one argument.

*edit, after changes:*

you could get rid of the promise and async to simplify your code. 
Just a note on async/await - if the **await**ed expression isn't a promise then it is cast into one automatically. In your current code you either need to use it like a promise (chain a .then() for example) or await it.

Anyways, here is an example that is just using a callback:

```
function httpGet(options, cb) {
  http.get(options, res => {
    // simplified version without error handling
    let output = []; 
    res.on('data', d => output.push(d)); // or concat to a string instead?
    res.on('end', () => cb(output));
  });
}

httpGet(options, res => {
// building the alexa response, all your intent handler code that needs the response from your request
})
```

Comment: So do you mean I need to use `const myResult = await httpGet(resolve)`?  Sorry, not sure what you actually mean as this is new to me.

Comment: what I meant was that you are not resolving the promise that you are returning from httpGet. Somewhere in your new Promise you need to call resolve(<with whatever you want to return>).
You are already calling reject, you just need to add the call to resolve (like right after request.end() for example)

Comment: In the logs from my handler I'm getting "received: [object Promise]" and then speechText: Promise {<pending>}.  Should the async function be broken into two functions, whereas one of the functions is basically a synchronous function returning a Promise, and the other is the async function using await?

Comment: ok, this is a bit mixed up now :)
Your usage of the request is basically a synchronous operation, I think we can simplify this a bit - I will update my answer with what I think could be a doable solution.